# In C#.Net Given a window handle how to force a window to full screen?

Tags: c#, window, fullscreen, handle

I've obtained the handle to a processes Main Window and would like to force that
window to full screen.  I'm programming in c#.Net with .Net framework V2.0 SP1

Comment: If your question isn't answered within 12 hours, I'll paste some code that's on a machine I can't access right now. But I doubt it'll take that long :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [article that shows you how to do this.](http://www.vesic.org/english/blog/winforms/full-screen-maximize/)  It requires P/Invoke into the Windows API for most of the calls, however.

Answer (score 2):

```
    public void MaximizeForm(IntPtr handle)
    {
        Control c = Control.FromHandle(handle);
        Form c_form = c as Form;
        if (c_form != null)
        {
            if (c_form.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { MaximizeForm(handle); }));
            }
            else
            {
                c_form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548(VS.85).aspx) - [p/invoked](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/ShowWindow.html), of course.